# How to understand minus operator between TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, timestamp

```
mysql> select timestamp('2017-06-21 23:45:01') - timestamp('2017-06-21 23:44:58');
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| timestamp('2017-06-21 23:45:01') - timestamp('2017-06-21 23:44:58') |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                  43 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select version();
+------------+
| version()  |
+------------+
| 5.7.16-log |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Obviously, it is not calculated as `timestamp`. Please advise.

Comment: The mysql timestamp function and the unix_timestamp functions return different values. The timestamp function returns the date/time as a number, but it's like 20170621101000.000000 for "2017-06-21 10:10:00". The unix_timestamp function returns the number of seconds since "1970-01-01 00:00:00"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `TIMEDIFF()` or `TIMESTAMPDIFF()`

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/XSLS27085)**

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(timestamp('2017-06-21 23:45:00') , timestamp('2017-06-21 23:44:58'));
-- result: 00:00:02.

SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2017-06-21 23:45:00','2017-06-21 23:44:58'); 
-- result: -2
```